# How do I use the service on Android Top 5

Tags: service, android-service, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-wake-lock

I've used a `service` in my program but the `top 5 Android` phone goes to **sleep** as soon as the **service does nothing**.

It works on Android 4 without any problems.

pls help me.

> in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       startService(new Intent(this , MyService.class));
  }
}
```

> in Service

```
public class MyService extends android.app.Service {

private PowerManager pm;
private WifiManager wm;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //do something code

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        final PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK), "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiManager.WifiLock lock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "LockTag");
        lock.acquire();

        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MyService.class);
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, restartServiceIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        long thirtySecondsFromNow = 1000;
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, thirtySecondsFromNow, restartServicePendingIntent);

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);



        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
}
```

> in Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app.service">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="my"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />

</application>
```

Comment: From android 6, background services are restricted, read the documents and change your pattern

Comment: @Mala Can a website or blog or article to solve this problem I suggest this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: @Mala Thank you. Could a simple piece of code to write a service that does not have this problem?